# Use of [any other] in a sentence

Tags: adjectives

> The Nile is longer than **any** river in India. 
>   The Nile is longer than **any other** river in the world.

In both of these above sentences, we are comparing one river with the rest.  But still we have used **any other** in second and **any** in first sentence. Any rules regarding this usage please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Any' is applicable when we compare **anything that is not a member of the group** compared.

Said that,

> The Nile is longer than **any** river in India. (The Nile is not an Indian river.)

If you use the Ganges instead of the Nile, you need to write the above sentence as:

> The Ganges is longer than **any other** river in India. (The Ganges is an Indian river.)

So, 'any other' is used when we compare **anything that is a member of the group** compared.

In your example, as The Nile is a member of the group of rivers in the world, the second sentence requires 'any other' instead of 'any':

> The Nile is longer than **any other** river in the world.