# Any other car/cars ever made

Tags: grammar

> Tesla 3 stands out from **any other car/cars** ever made today.

As for as I know, if you use **any+noun** (it should be singular, right?) MOREVER, according to my sentence ''any'' was followed by ''**other**''-->**any other**.

- So, should I make it singular-> **any+singular noun** =any other car OR
- should it be **any other+plural noun** =anym other cars(because the ''other'' takes the plural noun.)

I have just heard a middle aged American said ''any other car ever made'' but **grammatically** I think this is wrong(not sure though that's why I am asking hehe)

Comment: For related questions and answers, see: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70107/use-of-any-other-in-a-sentence            and          http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00029.htm

Comment: You could say either "any other car" (singular) or "all other cars" (plural).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any other** is a perfectly grammatical and idiomatic phrase. It means **any X other than the X or X's previously referred to.**

The relevant noun should be singular because it is referring to any single exemplar of a class, namely the class of all items in the class of X other than the designated ones.